# Bash Script execute commands from a file but if cancel on to jump on next one

Tags: bash

Im tring to make a script to execute a set of commands from a file

the file for example has a set of 3 commands perl script-a, perl script-b, perl script-c, each command on a new line and i made this script

```
#!/bin/bash
for command in `cat file.txt`
do
   echo $command
   perl $command

done
```

The problem is that some scripts get stuck or takes too long to finish and i want to see their outputs. It is possible to make the bash script in case i send CTRL+C on the current command that is executed to jump to the next command in the txt file not to cancel the wole bash script.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **`trap 'continue' SIGINT`** to ignore <kbd>**Ctrl+c**</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ignore & continue on Ctrl+c (SIGINT)
trap 'continue' SIGINT

while read command
do
   echo "$command"
   perl "$command"
done < file.txt

# Enable Ctrl+c
trap SIGINT
```

Also you don't need to call `cat` to read a file's contents.

Comment: This isn't going to jump to the next command in the file when Ctrl+C is pressed.

Comment: @dogbane: Good point, thanks for pointing it out. I made a correction.

Comment: The first line of your answer says "SIGNINT" instead of "SIGINT" - I tried to edit it but I have to change at least 6 characters so I couldn't.

Comment: One question here if you don't use the cat command how do you read the file content then?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for scr in $(cat file.txt)
do
 echo $scr

 # Only if you have a few lines in your file.txt,
 # Then, execute the perl command in the background
 # Save the output.
 # From your question it seems each of these scripts are independent

 perl $scr &> $scr_perl_execution.out &

done
```

You can check each of the output to see if the command is doing as you expect. If not, you can use `kill` to terminate each of the command.

Comment: This will background each process, not "forward" an interrupt.

Comment: It does, however, preclude the necessity of using Control-C to abort a stuck script to allow the next one to proceed.